# IBM SBT extension property not working

Tags: ibm-sbt, ibm-connections

the example code on 
https://greenhouse.lotus.com/sbt/SBTPlayground.nsf/JavaScriptSnippets.xsp#snippet=Social_ActivityStreams_Controls_Simple_Stream_All_Extensions

I can see all extensions UI being displayed, but three of four configured extension do not work
1. save in extension does not work
2. commenting in extension does not work
3. delete in extension does not work

can see errors on all three of them on developer tools

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is previously answered by Francis [SBT javascript library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036622/sbt-javascript-library)

basically the playground uses dojo layers, the controls don't work with dojo layers.

Download the Toolkit

Extract the Tomcat Instance

Point the Instance to Greenhouse (Edit Managed-Beans.xml for sbt.samples.web)

Try the Control from

> `https://host:8443/`

Navigate to the Control and Run it.

it should work from there.

Comment: I am not using tomcat, but IBM Notes, Xpages. How can I get it work there? why do you guys put up the control examples on playground that does not work?

Comment: you should look at Francis' post and work from there. you can always log an issue from GitHub.